# Are there any solutions that lock windows 7 so that a user can only access a specific application?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, blocking

This use case scenario applies for example to a POS terminal, whereby once windows 7 is booted up, if the user logs in, he or she can only access that particular application. The user has no way of accessing windows explorer, nor even the desktop. What would be the best cost effective solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Windows 7, I would suggest using a combination of [Applocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548340(WS.10).aspx) and group policy to apply restrictions to the approved users of the machine.